# Polymer 1.0 Data binding and accessing ajax response object

Tags: javascript, html, json, polymer-1.0

I am new to polymer and I am trying to create a custom service that takes a request and sends back a response. However, I am facing an issue of accessing the response object even though I can see the object is being set in the service page.

Please see the service code: x-custom.html

```html
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

<dom-module id="x-custom">
<style>
</style>
<template>
<iron-ajax
      id="ajax"
      url=""
      handle-as="json"
      on-response="hresponse"
      debounce-duration="300">
</iron-ajax>

</template>
<script>

  Polymer({

    is: 'x-custom',
 properties: {
      user: String,
      responseData:{
        type:Object,
        notify:true
      }

     },

attached: function() {
      this.$.ajax.url = "http://myapitesing/api/users/"+this.user;
      this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
    },

  hresponse: function(request) {
        // Make a copy of the loaded data
        respObj = request.detail.response; 
        if(respObj){
          //console.log(respObj);
          this.responseData = respObj;
          alert(respObj.email);
        }
      }

  });

</script>
</dom-module>
```

Now see the element that access the service: user-details.html

```html
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="x-custom.html">

<dom-module id="user-details">
    <style>

    </style>

<template>
    
        <x-custom user="6f299d3cb8214c079433d7bb98a4a5ed" responseData={{responseData}} ></x-custom> 
           
           <h1>{{responseData.email}}</h1>
           
</template>
    <script>
       Polymer({
                is: 'user-details'
          });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Now I call the user-details element in my idex.html in the following way

```html
<user-details></user-details>
```

It successfully fetches the details, however, {{responseData.email}} does not show the email string in the user-details.html page.

If i try fetch the same value in the x-custom.html page, i can see the responseData.email value. (see the alert in hresponse function inside x-custom.html)

Kindly help me, and let me  know if I am missing somewhere.

Comment: Check this data binding tutorial, maybe you need to create a custom element to pass the data in an attribute -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rXJ5lJ5_TA

Comment: Thanks but this is a tutorial for polymer 0.5. I guess it wont help much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note** I haven't taken both your elements and tested this, but my guess is that your problem is in your `<user-details>` line where you do:

```
    <x-custom user="6f299d3cb8214c079433d7bb98a4a5ed" responseData={{responseData}} ></x-custom>
```

Unless this is a typo, it definitely isn't binding to `responseData` because your attribute is in camelCase.  You need to do:

```
    <x-custom user="6f299d3cb8214c079433d7bb98a4a5ed" response-data={{responseData}} ></x-custom>
```

You may also need to make `responseData` in `<x-custom>` a property with `notify: true`; I always forget.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to fetch data by extending from other custom-element, then Polymer 1.0 currently does not support extending custom elements. 
You can find this shown in the docs at this link:
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#type-extension

Comment: I think i am not able clarify my question here:
I am not trying to extend element. I am trying to create a service element on which I will pass a input to json url, the response of which I want to display in the another page and not the page in which the service element is defined.


example:


<service-element user="userID"  responseData={{responseData}}> </service-element>

How can i use the response data in another page? I know this is possible with polymer 0.5